# iPhone dev. handling a list of files

Tags: iphone, file, nsarray

In my Phone app I need to put into an array all the file titles at a certain path, how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
// Contains the names of all files in the specified directory.
NSArray *files = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:path error:NULL];
```

If you want the full path to an item, simply prepend `path`. You can also filter out directories using `fileExistsAtPath:isDirectory:`. See the [NSFileManager reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for more information.